# How to link the TableAdapter to my Project?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a windows form application who using MSSQL Database.

When I'm trying to access one of the tableAdapters, I can't access the `GetBy` and `FillBy` methods, as seen there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOcmf.jpg

While the `GetBy` and `FillBy` methods are already created: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8kDu.png

What is the problem? Why don't I have access to the `GetBy` and `FillBy` methods?

Btn_click:

```
 private void button_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox_login_loading.Visible = true;
            moveControlX(button_login, 50, Direction.Left); // move left for progress bar
            moveControlX(button_login, 50, Direction.Right); // return button to place.
        }
```

Comment: You haven't instantiated it.  Look up the [new keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Put relevant code in the question... not an image.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I'm not sure what is the relevant code.

Comment: @Billie the stuff in `button_login_Click()`... so any of the C# code  directly related to the problem you are having.

Comment: @Brian I've use a TableAdapter before - I didn't use the `new` key word. as far as I know, it's a static method.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I have no idea how is that relevant, but see edit.

Comment: @Billie because seeing your code is much easier to debug than seeing an image of your code. Some people don't click on external links (with the exception of a jsfiddle or sqlfiddle) to figure out what is wrong with your code (i.e. like when some people just link to their site and expect us to `View Source`). Having the line that breaks in your code would help, as you left out the stuff that is actually causing you a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to 'new' it up.

```
public void button_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ReadersTableAdapter rdrsTblAdapter = new ReadersTableAdapter();
     rdrsTblAdapter.GetBy();
     rdrsTblAdapter.FilBy();
}
```

Comment: Oh .. well. what a shame. last time I used the DataGridView , and it been coded automatically by VS. XD. thanks again!